# Инициализация сервера

Tags: java, jsp, cookie, servlet, сессия

Всем привет, продолжая изучать javaEE (servlets) столкнулся с проблемой.
Использую куки, хранящие какую локаль использовать юзеру.

Суть вопроса, хочу, чтобы, когда юзер входил на сайт, еще до загрузки стартовой jsp страницы в его сессию записывался атрибут, взятый из куки.

Код показывающий, что я хочу:

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
for(Cookie cookie:cookies){
    if(cookie.getName().equals("LOCAL")){
        req.getSession().setAttribute("local",cookie.getValue());
    }
}
```

Куда можно вставить этот кусок кода? Или же по-другому как-нибудь сделать можно?

Comment: если страница грузится быстро то он может не успеть.

Comment: вот да, с этим уже столкнулся